# Как получить JSON от АПИ для андроид приложения

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

Хочу получить апи от https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details

я не понимаю, как мне получить сам ответ JSON, а то есть список вроде title, year и тд, не понимаю как отсюда мне получить данные для своего POJO. Во всех статьях относительно работы с АПИ этот момент опускается, а именного этого я и не могу понять. Все примеры, что пришлось просмотреть выглядели так - у нас есть базовый URL, и есть запрос вроде 
@GET("getTop")
    fun getMovies(): Call>

но как я узнаю, как мне составить POJO, откуда взять эти данные, не понятно

Comment: Судя по запросу речь идет про Retrofit, почитай сначала документацию как он работает: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Касаемо Pojo объекта, ниже в доке есть структура того что вернет апи, необходимо просто переписать эту структуру в Class руками, либо скопировать json и сгенерировать на его основе объект.

Comment: на счет ретрофита понятно, не особо понятно на счет того откуда взять эту структуру ответа. То есть у меня есть часть ссылки - базовый URL, есть вторая часть URL, которая пишется в ГЕТ запросе, а вот откуда взять эти данные для POJO не понятно(

Comment: Прямо в доке ниже есть большое поле Responses, там и есть информация о том что вернет апи.